# Playwright Github Actions "Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers" error with webkit / matrix / pnpm

Tags: github-actions, webkit, playwright, pnpm

my current workflow file, to run tests in Playwright using matrix to run 3 projects and pnpm, looks like this.

Somehow for webkit I get this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Also I would like to check for existing cache also in the first job. Anyone got experience with it?

The other 2 jobs of the matrix work fine...

```
name: Playwright Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]
    types: [synchronize, ready_for_review]
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  PLAYWRIGHT_CONTAINER_IMAGE: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.41.2-jammy
  NODE_VERSION: 18
  TEST_URL: ${{ vars.TEST_URL }}
  TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME: ${{ vars.TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME }}
  TEST_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TEST_ADMIN_PASSWORD }}
  TEST_USERNAME: ${{ vars.TEST_USERNAME }}
  TEST_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TEST_PASSWORD }}
  ALLURE_ENDPOINT: ${{ vars.ALLURE_ENDPOINT }}
  ALLURE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ALLURE_TOKEN }}
  ALLURE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ vars.ALLURE_PROJECT_ID }}

jobs:
  cache-and-install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ${{ github.env.PLAYWRIGHT_CONTAINER_IMAGE }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install pnpm
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v3
        with:
          version: 8
          run_install: false

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: 'pnpm'

      # Correctly setting the store path
      - name: Determine pnpm store path
        run: echo "STORE_PATH=$(pnpm store path)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      # Debugging: Echo the STORE_PATH to ensure it's correctly set
      - name: Echo pnpm store path
        run: echo "Store path is $STORE_PATH"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

      # This step caches the pnpm store directly, which includes node_modules
      - name: Cache pnpm store and node_modules
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            ${{ github.env.STORE_PATH }}
            **/node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-${{ hashFiles('**/pnpm-lock.yaml') }}

      - name: Store Playwright's Version
        run: |
          PLAYWRIGHT_VERSION=$(npx playwright --version | awk '{print $2}')
          echo "Playwright's Version: $PLAYWRIGHT_VERSION"
          echo "PLAYWRIGHT_VERSION=$PLAYWRIGHT_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Setup Playwright
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps

      # Preparing cache for Playwright browsers. Actual caching happens at the end of the job.
      - name: Cache Playwright Browsers
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/ms-playwright
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-playwright-${{ github.env.PLAYWRIGHT_VERSION }}

  playwright-tests:
    needs: cache-and-install
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ${{ github.env.PLAYWRIGHT_CONTAINER_IMAGE }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - name: 'Admin - Desktop Chrome'
            project: 'Admin - Desktop Chrome'
          - name: 'Driver - Mobile Android'
            project: 'Driver - Mobile Android'
          - name: 'Driver - Mobile iOS'
            project: 'Driver - Mobile iOS'

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Restoring the pnpm store and node_modules cache
      - name: Restore pnpm store and node_modules cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            ${{ github.env.STORE_PATH }}
            **/node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-${{ hashFiles('**/pnpm-lock.yaml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-

      - name: Restore Playwright Browsers cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/ms-playwright
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-playwright-${{ github.env.PLAYWRIGHT_VERSION }}

      - name: Run Playwright Test
        run: npx playwright test --project="${{ matrix.project }}"
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Can you copy the full error text into the question so it's searchable/accessible? ["Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers"](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/17975) is probably the most critical piece of information here, yet it can't be found except with OCR and won't be indexed in searches for people looking to help, or with the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to run it locally from your docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.41.2-jammy`? Is that passing?